# Suppress Outlook permissions warning in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, outlook

Sometimes when using Outlook subroutines from MS Access I'll get a permission prompt:

"A program is trying to access e-mail address information stored in Outlook. If this is unexpected, click Deny and verify your antivirus software is up-to-date."

with the option to allow access for 1 minute up to 10 minutes. Is there a way I can either ignore this prompt automatically or set it to auto-choose 10 minutes each time?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is using [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) 
I use it in Vbscript and Ruby, VBA is also possible.

Here an example in vbscript that lists the contents of a PST file.

```
Set session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
file = "c:\test\archive_test.pst"
Call session.LogonPstStore(file)
Set IPMRoot = session.Stores.DefaultStore.IPMRootFolder
total =0
subtotal = 0
For Each Folder In IPMRoot.Folders
  Wscript.Echo ""
  Wscript.Echo Folder.Name
  Wscript.Echo ""
  For Each msg In folder.items
    Wscript.Echo "  " & Msg.Subject & " " & Msg.Size & " " & Msg.SenderEmailAddress
    subtotal = subtotal + Msg.Size
  Next
  Wscript.Echo "subtotal: " & formatnumber(subtotal,0)
  total = total + subtotal
Next
Wscript.Echo "total: " & formatnumber(total,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply, by going into Outlook, Tools - > Trust Centre - > Trust Centre Settings - > Programmatic Access. Set the option to either "Warn me about suspicious activity when my antivirus software is inactive or out-of-date" provided your AV is flagged as Valid, or "Never warn me about suspicious activity" but you need to be aware this will suppress other valid issues as well.

[Microsoft Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/I-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-e-mail-address-information-or-sending-e-mail-on-my-behalf-df007135-c632-4ae4-8577-dd4ba26750a2)